# Merging duplicate features in a dataset but keeping all the attributes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, merge, fields-attributes

I have a polygon shapefile, in which there are many duplicate records (duplicate in the spatial sense, but with different attributes). What I want to do is merge all features that have the exact same geometry but keep the attributes from all of the polygons. Is this possible to do?

For an example, if I had the following as an input and all three features has the same geometry.

[image]

Then I want something like this at the end

[image]

Comment: You might be able to get it by using the Find Identical tool (using Shape as the Field value) followed by the Pivot Table tool.

Comment: Sadly I'm only running Basic so no Find Identical tool

Comment: Have you tested Dissolve? I think it will merge stacked polygons that have identical attributes into one polygon.

Answer (score 1):

The key here is creation of what I call digital signature of the shape:

```py
arcpy.AddField_management("POLYGONS", "SIGNATURE", "TEXT")
arcpy.CalculateField_management("POLYGONS", "SIGNATURE","str(!Shape!.centroid.X)+str(!Shape!.centroid.Y)")
arcpy.AddField_management("POLYGONS", "COMBO","TEXT")
# run this on combo field
aDict={}
def Combine(a,b):
 if a in aDict:  aDict[a]+=[b]
 else: aDict[a]=[b]
 return ";".join(aDict[a])
#--------------------
Combine( !SIGNATURE!, !INFO! )
# and dissolve
arcpy.Dissolve_management("POLYGONS","../dissolved.shp", "SIGNATURE", "COMBO LAST")
```

[image]

I hope the rest is obvious